# Class name passed in generic parameter of ArrayList

Tags: java

I am beginner in Java. I cannot understand these lines even after a long try.

```
private ArrayList <Lot> lots;
lots = new ArrayList<Lot>();
```

Can anyone describe how this works when a class name is passed to a `ArrayList<>` parameter?

Comment: Google for "Java generics tutorial"

Comment: If you're a beginner, you should continue reading your textbook; this will be covered.  (FYI, this is the syntax for *generics*: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

Answer (score 1):

From [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html),

The following code snippet without generics requires casting:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("hello");
String s = (String) list.get(0);
```

When re-written to use generics, the code does not require casting:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("hello");
String s = list.get(0);   // no cast
```

Answer (score 1):

These are [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), a feature introduced in Java 5.

In a nutshell, it means that every element in `lots` is a `Lot` - you cannot add `Integer`s or `String`s to it, and whenever you `get` an element from the list you get a `Lot` instance, so you can do things like this: `lots.get(0).someMethodOfLot();`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `ArrayList <Lot> lots= new ArrayList<Lot>();`
It simply means you are creating an ArrayList which can contain an Object of type `Lot`.

If you try to add any other type of element to this list, it will give you compile time error. It helps detect errors at compile time and makes your code safe.

This feature is provide by generics. Now the question comes why do we need generics.

The uses of Generics

1. Stronger type checks at compile time.
   A Java compiler applies strong type checking to generic code and issues errors if the code violates type safety. Fixing compile-time errors is easier than fixing runtime errors, which can be difficult to find.
2. Elimination of casts.The example of this is provided by Rakesh Kr
3. Enabling better code reusability such as implementation of generic algorithms.
   By using generics, programmers can implement generic algorithms that work on collections of different types, can be customized, and are type safe and easier to read.